# Invoke method in Func when passed as parameter

Tags: reflection, delegates, c#-4.0

I was creating a Func as parameter input to another method, but how do I invoke that?

The following code describes my work:

I call Foo with:

```
Foo(x => x.SlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50)));
```

My method Foo:

```
public void Foo(Func<CacheExpiration, TimeSpan> cacheExpiration)
{
....
inside here I want to call RefreshCache, but how?.. cacheExpiration.??

}
```

The CacheExpiration :)

```
public class CacheExpiration
        {
            TimeSpan timeSpan;
            bool sliding;

            public TimeSpan SlidingExpiration(TimeSpan ts)
            {
                this.timeSpan = ts;
                this.sliding = true;
                return ts;
            }
            public TimeSpan AbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan ts)
            {
                this.timeSpan = ts;
                return ts;
            }

            public bool RefreshCache(MetaObject mo)
            {
                //some logic....
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: The question doesn't entirely make sense. The parameter to the function `Foo` is a delegate, which on demand, can turn a `CacheExpiration` instance into a `Timespan`. The `Foo` method does not have a reference to an existing `CacheExpiration`instance to pass to the delegate. What`CacheExpiration` object do you wish to call `RefreshCache` on? How does the delegate parameter help in this regard? It doesn't even return a `CacheExpiration` object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly then the Func cacheExpiration takes a CacheExpiration instance and returns a TimeSpan. So I could see the body of Foo being:

```
TimeSpan ts = cacheExpiration.SlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
//or
TimeSpan ts2 = cacheExpiration.AbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
```

This doesn't line up with the lamda in your example so I'm guessing from that you really want cacheExpiration to be a Func that takes a Timespan and returns a TimeSpan. But this wouldn't work for the RefreshCache method as it takes a MetaObject and returns a boolean.

Comment: NServiceBus can be configured like:
NServiceBus.Configure.With().Log4Net<YourAppender>(a => a.YourProperty = "value");
why I cant do something similar? 
Foo(x => x.SlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50)));

Comment: In visual studio you could get the signature of the .Log4Net<AppenderSkeleton> method from NServiceBus by going to its definition. It looks like they are passing a function to configure the generic type.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ts = cacheExpiration(yourCacheExpiration);
```